# How to get listarray from firebase with condition?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

i want to get listarray of data in firebase and put it in my listview , but i cant add the condition ..

this is the firebase.

```
"Sendmail" : {
"-LkYHbH6FfiR-8ua7RQS" : {
  "deskripsi" : "coba",
  "perihal" : "coba",
  "username_from" : "rezkysaputra96",
  "username_to" : "hendra_admin"
},
"-LkbF2gEg6Q-cre8gSnd" : {
  "deskripsi" : "example2",
  "perihal" : "example2",
  "username_from" : "rezkysaputra96",
  "username_to" : "hendra_admin"
},
"-LkbF7YTY5yr7nMlAZss" : {
  "deskripsi" : "example3",
  "perihal" : "example3",
  "username_from" : "rezkysaputra96",
  "username_to" : "nurhamid123"
}
```

}

and this is my code ,this is get all data from "sendmail" , but i want get data from "sendmail" with some condition of value..

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sendmail");
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Sendmail.class).toString();
            arrayList.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

how can i get list data from sendmail where username_to = hendra_admin ?
thanks , im new in firebase and java.

Comment: use orderbychild("key").equal(value)

Comment: on databasereference ? its give me an error

Comment: use reference.child("node name").child("key").orderBychild("key").?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: alex: no , i still searching the solution

Comment: the solution of my code on the bottom of comment , thanks . its solve !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that i've found on this forum too . 
thanks . 
this is my code now .

```
public class OutboxFragment extends Fragment {


ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
public String getusername;
public String uid;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

public OutboxFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outbox, container, false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    dapatdatauser(uid);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference.child("Sendmail").orderByChild("username_from").equalTo("rezkysaputra96");
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Map data = (Map ) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String name = (String) data.get("perihal");
            arrayList.add(name);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    return view;

}

public void dapatdatauser(String iduser){
    // Mendapatkan DataUsers Berdasarkan uid sesuai login
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference query = reference.child("DataUsers").child(iduser);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Memasukkan data kedalam variabel username
            getusername = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Query` class to filter your query. See the [Firebase reference page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) for working with lists of data. Simply put, you need to order your query -using one of the `orderBy..` methods- first and then filter it. In your case, you need to use `orderByChild` because you want to filter your result based on the child `username_to`. Then use `equalTo` to filter the result. This should returns what you want:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("Sendmail").orderByChild("username_to").equalTo("hendra_admin");
```

Comment: and how to get the query to list view ?